# onreadystatechange works in IE11 but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, web

My Code is.

```
$(function()
{
  getConfig();
});

function getConfig()
{   
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest; 
  var str = "http://www.google.com.pk"; 
  req.open("GET", str, true);
  req.onreadystatechange = reqHandler;
  req.send(null);   
}

function reqHandler(req1)
{   
  alert("Good");
}
```

this code work fine in IE11 but not in other browsers like FireFox, Safari, Chrome. reqHandler function does not get called. Thanks

Comment: This is a cross-origin request, so most likely browsers do not even fire a readystatechange event, because they do not even start executing the request because of Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
```

You can add the parenthesis if you want to, but you can't leave out the `new` keyword as you'll need a new instance of the `XMLHttpRequest` object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I added the new keyword and it worked for other browsers but not for FireFox.

Comment: @SarfrazAhmed - Firefox has issues with cross domain ajax calls, can't think of any other reason it wouldn't work.